# Post 'older' and 'newer' navigation links are not showing in my blogger blog

Tags: javascript, css, templates, blogger

I'm new here and I need someone to please help me find out why my 'older' and 'newer' navigation links are not showing in my blogger blog. I contacted the template designer several times but haven't received any reply. Please see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgHDn.png.

Here's my blog link so you can inspect:
https://vandeweybalao.blogspot.com

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: seems like the designer has updated the theme, but the screenshot maybe old

Comment: Hi Joykal Infotech thanks for the reply. I made few customizations on the template so it will look the way I want except for the said navigation links. I updated the screenshot to avoid confusion. I re-uploaded/copied paste the original html code but still the problem persist.

Comment: Hello @vantimist sorry to say but I look over the code and couldn't find anything which might be causing the problem. Maybe that's a premium feature.

Comment: Hi Joykal Infotech, I just solved my problem by just ticking the 'Show Email Post Links' under 'Main Page Options' and the 'older' and 'newer' navigation links are now showing. Anyway thanks so much for your effort.

Comment: Its good to see that you figured it out. !! Cheers.